# Automated Voice Calls from Zabbix to Cell Phone at 3am?

Tags: zabbix

Is there a way to have Zabbix place a call to a given user's cell phone in case of high priority issues that happen at 3am?

My original plan was to use Asterisk and Festival as part of a Zabbix alert script, but it has proved to be to complex for me...

Does anyone know of an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use [PagerDuty](http://www.pagerduty.com/) for this, and it is amazing. Like you, I thought about integrating with Asterisk, but it all proved to be too fragile for my liking. PagerDuty integration is dead-simple - they have plugins available for nearly every popular monitoring system.

[Here's](https://github.com/PagerDuty/pagerduty-zabbix-py) a Zabbix plugin that will let you use PagerDuty for notifications.

Comment: Stack Exchange uses PagerDuty as well.

Comment: PagerDuty is very interesting, but for a support team of about 7 people it's surprisingly expensive!  (~$1,512/year)

Comment: Well, you're paying them to manage the infrastructure that proved too complex for you. At some point, you need to be okay paying for things that aren't your core competency.

Answer (score 3):

You can give [OpsGenie](http://www.opsgenie.com) a try (disclosure: I'm the founder). It's a cloud based service and rather [easy to hook it up](http://support.opsgenie.com/customer/portal/articles/894823-zabbix-integration) with Zabbix to notify users via phone calls, as well as iPhone and Android push notifications, and SMS. You can forward alerts to OpsGenie by forwarding alerts via email, or executing a custom alertscript.
Users can tier notifications methods and OpsGenie would try each notification method till the user sees the alert.

In addition to the free trial, OpsGenie offers a free tier for up to 2 users. If you'd like to give it a try, ping me and we'd be happy to help you get it up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Is it absolutely essential that it be a call and not an SMS?

We looked at the options described here and settled on sending a text message to the oncall's phone via email for critical alerts. All the major providers will send an sms over email ("myNumber@provider.net" etc)

As long as the oncall person expects an sms instead of a call, the effect is the same. Requires no special configuration in the monitoring system, and the price is certainly right.

Comment: This is what we do right now, but the problem is that admins are not being woken up by a simple SMS.  Including me ;)  We are looking for a more "alarming" solutions that will wake you up out of REM sleep at 3am.  The only thing that does that is a phone call.

Comment: @Kevin You need better ringtones.